# ListView_GetItemText crashes

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I am using Visual Studio 2013 in windows 10 machines and compiling 64 bit win 32 applications

I have populated a list control as below:

```
// got the handle of the list control
HWND m_list = GetDlgItem (hwnddialog, IDC_LIST );
LVITEM x;

//Inserted row items
x.mask = LVIF_TEXT; x.iItem = 0; x.pszText = L"text"; x.state = 0; 
x.stateMask = 0, x.iImage =0; x.lParam = 0; x.iSubItem = 0;
ListView_InsertItem( m_list, &x);
// Added column texts   ...
ListView_SetItemText(m_list,0,1,"text details");

// etc...  The list view shows fine. 
//-------------------------Now I am trying to read the text from listview ------
wchar_t tptr[512];
ListView_GetItemText(m_list , 0,0,   tptr, 5);
```

Whatever value I enter above for item, and subitem and whatever I provide as the size of tptr, ( even if I make it a local or global variable) the programcrashes after executing the above line:

***Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFC2CAA9AA (comctl32.dll) in sstwinpe64.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.***

It is necessary to develop this in Win32 as only Win32 programs are permitted to run in WinPE now. What is wrong in my program?
Thanking in advance,
Basudeb

Comment: Something is odd in your code -- you're setting the item text to an ANSI string (plain `"text details"` without an `L` prefix), but you're trying to retrieve an UNICODE string (`wchar_t[]`). In addition, both `ListView_SetItemText()` and `ListView_GetItemText()` work with `TCHAR`-based strings, whose actual types will vary depending on the `UNICODE` preprocessor macro.

Comment: Code looks fine in essence, but it dos not compile due to ANSI/Unicode mismatch. So I think you have posted fake code. Please post a [mcve] so that all doubt is removed. Please don't ever ask about code that you have not actually compiled and executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your project structure, but it seems that you have some mixture of ANSI, Unicode and wchar:

```
x.pszText = L"text"; 
ListView_SetItemText(m_list,0,1,"text details");
wchar_t tptr[512];
```

Comment: I am sorry about the mistake in reporting, I do have a L" before the code. This is not a fake code, but only the texts I had to modify due to reasons of privacy. Please note that all other Listview macros or messages are working fine except when I try to read getitem  or getitemtext.  I have tried all kinds of fixes for three days, and only when I  failed I am asking for help. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @rezdm As far as Windows programming is concerned Unicode == wchar.

Comment: @BasudebGupta if you can recreate the issue with a from-scratch program that uses fake values, that will be acceptable as well. If you find your bug while writing such a program, then that's also fine.

Comment: So, what is the answer?  I do not want to establish if it is a fake code or not. But the bug or problem does not go away. Is there a known issue with ListView_GetItemText like  this, and what are the fixes if any?

Comment: I have got a weird solution to the problem. It beats me, but it is one of those mysteries.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a weird solution to the problem. It beats me, but it is one of those mysteries.  Look at the actual (not fake) code carefully:

```
wchar_t dsk[3200];
ListView_GetItemText(m_list,i,0,dsk,32);  // Crashes as reported.
```

But I have modified it  now as below:
written a function:

```
BOOL GetItemText(HWND hlist,int nitem, int nsubitem, wchar_t * txt, int ln)
{
ListView_GetItemText(hlist,nitem,nsubitem,txt,ln);
return TRUE;

}
```

And modified my original call to :
    GetItemText(m_list,i,0,dsk,32);

And lo!   It works and does not crash.

Anyone can see thru this puzzle?  My problem is solved and I will go away. But the mystery will keep clanging like a heavy stone on the pothole-filled path of my coding .